# How to parse a txt file from a url in the exact format to a textview?

Tags: java, android, textview, parse-url

I am try to parse a txt file from a url to a textview in my application the text is being display but the text are not display in the right format as it is online like spaces, next line, paragraph e.t.c. simply put what i want is>

> CHAPTER 1
>
> INTRODUCTION TO MOBILE
>
> Majority of the population use mobile services.
>
> Mobile is a term used via a mobile device such as a mobile phone.

but I am getting

> CHAPTER 1 INTRODUCTION TO MOBILE Majority of the population use mobile services.Mobile is a term used via a mobile device such as a mobile phone.<< no space, no paragraph, no next line, how can i parse it to display exactly the way it is online.Thanks

```
public class GetNotePadFileFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            url = new URL(TextFileURL);

            bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

            while ((TextHolder2 = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

                TextHolder += TextHolder2;
            }
            bufferReader.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
            malformedURLException.printStackTrace();
            TextHolder = malformedURLException.toString();

        } catch (IOException iOException) {
            iOException.printStackTrace();

            TextHolder = iOException.toString();
        }

        return null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void finalTextHolder) {

        textView.setText(TextHolder);

        super.onPostExecute(finalTextHolder);
    }

}
```

Comment: bufferReader.readLine() is used to readLine, hence omitting the EOL and appeding character in-between in the EOL's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        while ((TextHolder2 = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {

            TextHolder += TextHolder2;
```

You read the text line by line.

Lines are separated by the newline character '\n'.

So to restore the original text you should add them again.

```
            TextHolder += TextHolder2 + "\n";
```